# disable music button

Tags: custom-roms, music, buttons

How can I disable the hardware music button on the side of my LG GW620?  I keep accidently triggering it in my pocket, causing random bursts of Foo Fighters when I sit down in a meeting.

Just disabling it while the screen is locked would be best, but completely disabling it would be better than nothing.

My GW620 has been upgraded to android 2.2 (Froyo) using the the [OpenEtna](http://openetna.com) firmware.  Prior to this I don't think the music button did anything at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try [Button Remapper](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=850464), but I am not 100% sure if your device is supported. if its not, you could contact the dev and see if he can add support, he recently added support for the Galaxy S devices.

**Edit**
Actually, from looking at that thread, it may be supported already. I see there are "media" actions that can be changed...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I have installed it but it looks like it doesn't support my device - I don't get any keys listed for remapping, just the Apply button.

Comment: Actually, I think you might be able to do this manually by editing the eve_qwerty.kl file.  I'm going to try this, but I'm going to accept your answer since it has helped me understand the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, this is a bit of a half-answer - I haven't worked it right the way though yet - but I think you could do something like the following using the (amazing) Tasker app.

```
ON 'Screen Off', IF current music track = "", SET Media Volume = 0
ON 'Screen On' set volume back to normal)
```

By checking for a currently playing track, it won't mute whilst you are genuinely listening to something just because the screen is then turned off.

Whilst it doesn't disable your phone as such, it would stop the music blearing out. You could also add a vibrate notification to warn you if this has happened.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app on Google Play Store for disable and re enable the music button. [Music Button Disabler for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rltmultimedia.serviceMusicButtonDisabler)

Hope this help.